# Sending images in an email in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, smtp, laravel-mail

I am trying to send an auto-reply to the newly registered user and I want to send them an image rather than the text but when I try to send the image the mail does send but the image received is broken. I studied many answers from StackOverflow as well tried many other solutions from the internet but nothing seems to be working.

**My mail class:**

```php
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class autoMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject("Subject")
            ->view('emails.autoemail');
    }
}
```

Here is my function which is calling this mail class.

```php
Mail::to($request->email)->send(new autoMail());
```

And last but not least my view which I am sending as an email.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Auto Email</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ asset('img/email.png') }}">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with _"image receive is broken"_ ? Maybe try embedding the image with `<img src="{{ $message->embed("img/email.png") }}">`

Comment: @Remul I have tried that as well it keeps loading the page and then says max execution time reached. And by "image receive is broken" I mean that when the registered user received the mail the image I am sending is broken.

Comment: And your image exists at `public/img/email.png`?

Comment: Yes it exist there when I type http://localhost:8000/img/email.png it does return the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually pass your data to the view via the `with()` method.

```php
class autoMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function build()
    {
        $image = env('APP_URL')."/img/email.png";

        return $this->subject("Subject")
            ->view('emails.autoemail')
            ->with(['image' => $image]);
    }
}
```

Once the data has been passed to the `with()` method, it will automatically be available in your view, so you may access it like you would access any other data in your Blade templates:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Email</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="{{ $image }}">
</body>
</html>
```